# Good resource for Pieces of Heart in Twilight Princess?

Tags: zelda-twilight-princess

I've reached the Twilight Realm (pretty much the endgame AFAIK) and have only 16 hearts. Considering doing that required me to get something like 30 PoH (just dungeon-crawling with no heart piece hunting only gets you 10 HCs in this game since it trades dungeon-crawling for side-questing), I think that's pretty impressive. However, by my calculations I'm only half done; I'm missing about 20 more PoH if it's possible, like in all other Zeldas, to get to 20 HC.

Anyone know a good resource, with pictures and descriptions, for getting all 50 (!!!) PoH? Obviously I missed a lot.

Comment: I don't understand why you would ask for a link to an external guide, rather than just ask where the pieces of heart are.  We would become the repository of information, not a piddly middle-ground site full of useful links.

Comment: @Strix I'm sure the information exists somewhere else, are you suggesting that someone should copy and paste all of it here?  That seems likely to be too much data for an answer, and we'd just be copying it anyways.

Comment: @bwarner I thought I read that policy somewhere, but maybe I was mistaken.  [This meta question](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/913/should-we-allow-the-quick-and-dirty-answer-that-merely-links-to-an-offsite-resour) has some more information and points on both sides of the argument.

Comment: @bwarner Even so, the question should ask for information, and the answerer should determine whether a good answer is a complete write-up on our site or a link to a pre-existing guide.

Comment: I asked for a guide because to answer this question with pics and descriptions of all the Heart Piece locations would either be a monumental effort or blatant plagiarism. Much like the Poe Souls, it's easier and less legally questionable to simply link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is such a guide built into the game. If you go to the fortune teller in Castle Town and ask for Love advice, you will be shown a picture of an as-yet-unclaimed Piece of Heart.

I *believe* you can ask multiple times in a row without risk of seeing a duplicate; the teller will go through all remaining pieces and then tell you there are no more. I *think*.

If you see a picture that you absolutely don't recognize from your play through the game, you've probably missed a grotto or secret cave in Hyrule Field. Ride Epona around all the walls and plateaus in the field and look for entrances.

If you must have descriptions, well, err, go to GameFAQs.

Answer (score 0):

GameFAQs?

- Descriptions: http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/928519-the-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess/faqs/45942
- Map: http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/928519-the-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess/faqs/46196

Answer (score 0):

[In no particular order](http://lmgtfy.com/?&q=twilight%20princess%20heart):

- [IGN](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/747/747622p1.html) (text)
- [StrategyWiki](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Twilight_Princess/Heart_Containers) (text)
- [SuperCheats](http://www.supercheats.com/guides/the-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess/heart-piece-location-guide/) (with screenshots)
- [ZeldaDungeon](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda11-twilight-princess-pieces-of-heart.php) (with maps & screenshots)
- [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/928519-the-legend-of-zelda-twilight-princess/faqs/45942) (text)
- [ZeldaUniverse](http://www.zeldauniverse.net/zelda/tp-heart-pieces/) (text)
- [LegendZelda](http://legendzelda.net/series/twilight-princess/heart-piece-locations/) (text, some screenshots)